# Retrieve All Account Contact Relationship records for a contact

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, query

I have a requirement, that I should Query all the Account Contact Relationship junctions records for a contact.
Could someone direct me to the Query?

I used the below Query but not able to retrieve records.

Select Id, Name,(SELECT AccountId,ContactId,Id,IsPrimary,Role FROM AccountContactRoles) from Contact where Id ='0037j00000XSyJG'

Thank you,
Vara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying the wrong object. It should be `AccountContactRelation`

e.g.

```
SELECT id, AccountId, ContactId, contact.Name FROM accountcontactrelation
```